# Android Resize images according to the screen size of the device

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-imageview

I hope someone can help me.
I have days looking for a way to Resize images in android according to the screen size of the device.
Sometimes the picture is fine but when used in a slightly larger image comes to be very small and not resized or adapted to the screen size.

For there I saw that for every image that wanted to join the project, was to add image in different sizes, Example: 80x80, 160x160,220x220,320xx320 (each has the same name.) and that helped resized.

Or did so but not me. sometimes the image is totally distorted.

This is the code I use for ImageView

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/inicio"
            android:background="@drawable/inicio1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"


            />
```

that I can do to make the image take an appropriate size according to the size of the screen.

Thank You

Comment: You need to set image in drawable as per aspect ratio of Screen.

Comment: i think your problem is d big screens, so change ur last dimensions to 400*400, let that be in xx folder, and fall back on ur dimensions

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/inicio"
            android:background="@drawable/inicio1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:scaleType:"fitXY"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"


            />
```

Comment: ah, is that I appeared incomplete.
I'll try that thanks.

Comment: You believe with that image suited to a tablet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different sized images in different folders.Put same image with different sizes i.e small size image for ldpi folder,slightly bigger for mdpi.You can refer the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi and xxhdpi

[image]

Comment: I already did, so that the image indicate the place in sizes 80x80, 160x160,220x220,320xx320 and each goes in those folders you mentioned but still does not work. look very blurry or disproportionate size

Comment: @alexandermatafonseca Because you are using square image and mobile screens are not square.

Comment: mmm're right about that are not square, what happened was that these measures I saw at one glance and take from there.

Measures you recommend me for pictures?
What measures use?

Comment: I think android for any device is taking me the 80x80 image and not because if all have the same name.

Comment: @alexandermatafonseca to show the images in proper aspect ratio use `android:src` instead of `android:background` , however in this case your images won't fill up the full screen. And mostly android devices are of 3:5 but not in all case. So be careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the images into their respective sizefolders? Like Android tells you here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Basically in the drawable folder you should have another set of folders with the names ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi. In these folders you should put your image with the same name but different image size. Look at the link for the different sizes suggested.

Comment: I already did, so that the image indicate the place in sizes 80x80, 160x160,220x220,320xx320 and each goes in those folders you mentioned but still does not work. look very blurry or disproportionate size

Comment: Works very well for me, have you made sure your sizes acctually are different? And the name is the same? Is it just the launcher icon? Does it work on any size?

Comment: if the sizes are different, I did 80x80, 160x160, 220x220 and 320x320 and if different names.
What did your image sizes ??

Comment: I think android for any device is taking me the 80x80 image and not because if all have the same name.

Comment: I just created a project with these folders, same names and different sizes. Using what google is using in their documentation. It works perfectly. Please make sure you have the right folder names and that they are all in the res folder. Also make sure you have different sizes on the images and the names are different